# How to find surface areas from a Mesh (.obj) File using Python

Tags: python, 3d, mesh

I am working on a python script that can find surface areas of planes with the same slope values in an obj file. I found a few modules that can help but none which actually had good documentation. For example, I would like to know surface areas of each face of a solid cuboid, which is in the form of an 3D Mesh (obj file).

My initial approach is to estimate normals and club all the triangles which have similar normals together, assume they are of the same face. Then add up their surface areas, but I am finding it difficult to achieve this using Python. I am open to using C++ too, if that is easier.

Is there any Python module that can help me achieve this. Any help on this would be really helpful ! Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.